# Sylius use another messages file

Tags: resources, switch-statement, translation, sylius

I would like to know how to switch for example from :

```
messages.en.yml
```

(because my site is on English right now and I guess I'm using that file right now) to

```
 messages.nl.yml
```

in case I want to view my shop in another language?

Answer (score 0):

I solved it by adding new locale on admin dashboard and after that what I did was:

I opened my parameter.yml and parameter.yml.dist and changed sylius.locale: to code of language I want to use .. but I saw some weird things on my admin dashboard after I changed language and that things looks like thise:

[image]

and I dont know how to solve this stuffs